# LWC. Issue with redirecting to GlobalAction with NavigationMixin

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I have a custom activity component, with 3 buttons. "New Task", "New Event", "Log a Call".

Onclick, i'm redirecting user to standard GlobalAction. For "New Task" and "New Event", it works fine, but when user trying to create "Log a Call", of first click action modal, display only "X" icon for close, but on second and next times it opens correctly.

In lightning it opens on the first attemp, but takes much more time than another actions. In Community it doesn't opens at all.

How to fix that?

My JS functions to redirect.

```
newTask(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__quickAction",
            attributes: {
              apiName: "Global.NewTask",
            },
            state: {
                recordId: this.recordId
            }
        });
    }

    newEvent(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__quickAction",
            attributes: {
              apiName: "Global.NewEvent",
            },
            state: {
                recordId: this.recordId
            }
        });
    }

    logACall(){
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: "standard__quickAction",
            attributes: {
                apiName: "Global.LogACall",
            },
            state: {
                recordId: this.recordId
            },
        })
    }
```

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5YGV.jpg)